# AOSP crop library

Tags: android, crop, android-source, android-4.4-kitkat

I need to extract AOSP library for crop intent (com.android.camera.action.CROP) and use it in my app so i can be sure that i will have it even if its for example TW device, etc.  I found this https://github.com/lvillani/android-cropimage but it is an older API, and i would like to include the KitKat one. So, if anyone knows where i can find the extracted library, or from where i can extract it, i'd be very thankful.

Answer (score 1):

So you can go and browse the source directly on the android google source here: [Gallery 3D on Google's Source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Gallery3D/). You can also go ahead and do a git clone on that repository:

```
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Gallery3D/
```

If that's not the repository you wan't, that site still has all the android repositories directly from the source.

If you want the class that responds to that action, see `com.cooliris.media.CropImage` - thanks to CommonsWare's comment below.

Comment: Actually, if you look at the manifest, it will be in the `com.cooliris.media.CropImage` class, as that is what responds to `com.android.camera.action.CROP`.

Comment: Ah my bad, I did a grep for the action and looked at the first thing that just defined it. That makes much more sense.

Comment: Thank you all, ill check it out as soon as i can and post feedback, but for now it looks to be what i was looking for.

Comment: Im missing build.gradle file for the module, how do i create one for Gallery3D?

Comment: @Sinisa I'm not sure what you are trying to do. You might want to post the error, but you also might want to create a new question if you need specific help related to gradle (I'm not very familiar with it)

Comment: I fixed gradle, but https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Gallery3D/ was to much for me to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the answer to my question but definitely is the way i solved it. So, since https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Gallery3D/ is the COMPLETE source for gallery, it was way to complicated to implement considering i needed only the crop functionality and would be left with a lot of overhead (there's a few hundred classes and drawables). So i finally went along with https://github.com/lvillani/android-cropimage, added it as a module in Android Studio, tweaked the UI a bit to my liking, and got it up and running in my app in no time (since its only a crop/pick-image library), and is used exactly the same as com.android.camera.action.CROP (same intents, and there's even an intent builder included for ease of use).

Hope this helps anyone in the future.